# Can I replace the URL Link with specific text when using Google Script for the getEditResponeURL code?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have used the below code in order to place the Google Form URL in to the spreadsheet
But I would like to know if I can replace the URL which can be very long, with a hyperlink 'EDIT FORM' text.

```
var formURL = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/(MY CODE)/viewform';
var sheetName = 'Responses';
var columnIndex = 8 ;

function getEditResponseUrls() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
  for(var i = 2; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i][0] != '' && data[i][columnIndex-1] == '') {
      var timestamp = data[i][0];
      var formSubmitted = form.getResponses(timestamp);
      if (formSubmitted.length < 1) continue;
      var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
      sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex).setValue(editResponseUrl);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you just have to the following changes to your code:

```
var editResponseUrl = formSubmitted[0].getEditResponseUrl();
var formula = '=HYPERLINK('+'"'+editResponseUrl+'"'+',"EDIT FORM")';
sheet.getRange(i+1, columnIndex).setFormula(formula);
```

The above snippet uses the `=HYPERLINK()` formula in Sheets in order to be able to create the hyperlink of the `editResponseUrl` with the `EDIT FORM` text. Afterwards, this formula is used by using the `setFormula()` method in Apps Script.

**Reference**

- [Class Range - setFormula](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula);
- [HYPERLINK Formula Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en).

Comment: @PeteMcKinnon I am glad my solution worked for your situation! :) If you found it helpful please don’t forget to mark the answer as accepted since others might encounter the same issue and it might be of help! Cheers!